# Выполнения условия при нажатии на кнопку в django

Tags: python, django, post, requests, get

Код в html:

```html
<form method='get'>
    <input type="submit" value="Удалить"  name="delete">
</form>
```

Код в views.py

```py
if request.GET.get('delete'):
    request.session.clear()
```

Почему при нажатии на кнопку меня переадресует на?
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?delete=Удалить`

Когда мне нужно так же оставаться на адресе:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

Как это сделать?

Comment: вас переадресует потому что вы используете метод `GET`. [Здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#GET) можете посмотреть, что происходит. Параметры, которые вы используете отдается в URI с символом `?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените метод `GET` на `POST`.

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Удалить" name="delete"/>
</form>

# view.py

if request.POST.get('delete'):
   requets.session.clear()
```

В этом случае параметры будут передаваться в теле запроса, а не в URL.

Еще одна причина перейти на `GET`, это то, что `GET` не должен использоваться с методами, которые меняют состояние сервера, а только для `read-only` операций.